# how do I handle a URI with spaces in a chef source attributes on Windows

Tags: windows, chef

I am trying to copy a package from a remote server, into my system and then use chef to install the same. 
Following is the code I use to copy the package

```
remote_file 'c:/repo/OpenOffice 4.1.0 (en-US) Installation Files' do
    source 'file:////10.132.17.53/e$/CHEFREPO/OpenOffice 4.1.0 (en-US) Installation Files'
end
```

But it is giving me an InvalidFileURI error. I guess it's because of the space in the source path. Any idea how to escape these spaces

Comment: Usually you escape special characters using backslashes. Have you tried that?